# Select all lines starting with a given string and ending with " with Regex

Tags: powershell, regex

Using Regex I would like to select all the contents between two " of all the lines that begin with this string:

```
[2]
     1 string data = "
```

I tried the following code:

```
(?<=\[2\][^=]+? 1 string data = ")[^"]+
```

But the problem is that if other " occur within the sentence, it does not select the whole sentence up to the last ", but the whole sentence up to the first " and with $ I could not solve it.

Example:

```
[2]
     1 string data = ""some text" in english" and "other""
```

Must become:

```
[2]
     1 string data = ""un pò di testo" in Italiano" and "other""
```

Not:

```
[2]
     1 string data = "some text".
```

Comment: 4 spaces, sure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this:

```
(?<=\[2\][^=]+?         1 string data = ").*(?=")
```